# Is this the correct way to use memset() in C?

Tags: c, memory, memset

So to start out I am a noob with C and am learning memory manipulation. I have a buffer that is called `void* buffer`. I then want to put an integer into the first 4 bytes of that buffer (since an int is 4 bytes but correct me if I am wrong). Would I do it like this:

```
memset(buffer, '9', sizeof(int))
```

If I am going about filling the first 4 bytes the wrong way please feel free to correct me.

Comment: What happened to buffer when you ran this code? You need to have some way to verify what you wrote to buffer e.g. a utility function to print the hex values of each byte otherwise you will struggle to learn. That will show you why this code doesn't do what you want. Also, '9' (the character) is quite a different thing to 9 (the integer).

Comment: Twice no. (1) I'm guessing `buffer` doesn't point anywhere yet.  (But if it does, show us how you declared `buffer`, and how you set it to point somewhere.)  (2) `memset` is only good for setting every byte of a region to something, so it's typically only good for (a) setting all characters of a string to the same character, or (b) setting all bytes of a data structure to 0.  If you want to set the first integer of an integer array, you'd rather have `buffer[0] = 9;` (although that won't work with `void *buffer`).

Comment: @SteveSummit your'e correct buffer is not pointing anywhere, I am just using it as an array to store both ints and chars but I want them to be exactly next to each other in memory. So from your explanation it sounds like I do not want to use memset.

Comment: @John Your bigger problem is that if `buffer` does not point anywhere yet you cannot use it for *anything*.  (Nobody is going to allocate memory for it to point to unless you do.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I am just using buffer as a packet to transfer data from client to server. But I want my "packet" to be filled from the front starting at memory address 0x01 since 0x00 is NULL, and not skipping any bytes in-between entries to the packet.

Comment: @SteveSummit I assume I would have to use type casting such as (int*)buffer = 9 and then increment it by sizeof(int)?

Comment: What kind of system are you targeting? How did you decide that memory at address 0x01 (and following) is available for your use?

Comment: @Blastfurnace This is part of my problem actually. I just assumed it was available without looking. Guess I have some reading to do before getting to the question I originally asked.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation

> ```
> #include <string.h>
> void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
> ```
>
> ***Description*** The `memset()` function fills the first `n` bytes of the memory area pointed to by `s` with the constant byte `c`. Return
> Value The `memset()` function returns a pointer to the memory area
> `s`.

So your call to `memset`:

```
memset(buffer, '9', sizeof(int))
```

will fill `sizeof(int)` bytes of memory referenced by the `buffer` with ASCII code of digit `'9'`